# Access web within AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'd like to define a lambda. When it receives a POST request, I'd like to make another POST request to an external uri (say, splunk or apigee or anything outside of AWS). Is this possible? Does Lambda allow the internet access? I googled but did not find a good answer for this one.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can run pretty much any code that you would run on a normal EC2 instance. For instance, if you write your Lambda in node.js you can use the `request` library to make HTTP calls out to other webservices. The same is true of Java or Python as long as you include whatever library you want to use to make the call in your Lambda. Just make sure you set the Lambda timeout high enough to allow your call(s) enough time to complete.

I wrote a blog post that shows a simple example of a Lambda calling out to a weather API(HTTP GET) to get weather for a zip code and post it in Slack: http://www.ryanray.me/serverless-slack-integrations

Comment: Your example on Slack integration with AWS using API GW & Lambda is awesome !! Very much helpful indeed !!!